# How to search for any matching unlinked URL and replace it with href?

Tags: javascript

My goal is to find all strings that match **[www.website.com](http://www.website.com)** or **website.com**.

If that address is not currently linked, then replace any matched string with...

`<a href="https://www.website.com">www.website.com</a>`

**or**

`<a href="https://www.website.com">website.com</a>`

**Here's what I have so far...**

```js
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/website.com/g, '<a href="https://www.website.com">www.website.com</a>');
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam minima, www.website.com suscipit expedita excepturi laboriosam website.com nesciunt accusantium quae placeat ex nostrum esse corrupti nisi hic velit commodi molestiae.</p>
```

But, I can't seem to account for addresses that already have the **www** in front of it.

Comment: How about `replace(/(www\.)?website\.com/g, '<a href="https://$&">$&</a>')`

Comment: when you replace website.com, it also replaces www.website.com, and then displays www.www.website.com so you need to make 2 replace, one for with www, one without. The one without can be done with a regex.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I just needed more regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a generic regex as

```
const regex = /(www.)?(\w+|\d+)+(\.com)/;
```

**demo**

```js
const str1 = "website.com";
const str2 = "www.website.com";
const str3 = "www.google.com";
const str4 = "www.regex101.com";
const regex = /(www.)?(\w+|\d+)+(\.com)/;

const result1 = str1.replace(regex, `<a href="https://www.$2.com">$1$2$3</a>`);
const result2 = str2.replace(regex, `<a href="https://www.$2.com">$1$2$3</a>`);
const result3 = str3.replace(regex, `<a href="https://www.$2.com">$1$2$3</a>`);
const result4 = str4.replace(regex, `<a href="https://www.$2.com">$1$2$3</a>`);

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
console.log(result3);
console.log(result4);
```